# Koin No definition found for class, but already declared

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, koin

Im trying to implement a Permission Injection using Koin as my D.I
however when i execute my ViewModel that requires the PermissionRepository i keep receiving the error.

> No definition found for class:'ni.com.repository.PermissionRepositoryImplement'. Check your definitions!

the current structure of the project is this.

**BaseApplication**

```
class BaseApplication : Application() {
    companion object{
        lateinit var context: BaseApplication
        val allAppModules = listOf(coilModule, permissionsModule, blurModule, remoteDataSourceModule, preferencesModule, databaseModule, viewModelModule)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        context = this
        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@BaseApplication)
            modules(allAppModules)
        }
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }
}
```

**PermissionModule** however i need an Activity to display the request for permissions. And following the Jetpack Navigation, i use my MainActivity as Base and injected in the Repository

```
val permissionsModule = module {
    scope<MainActivity> {
        scoped {
            PermissionRepositoryImplement(get<MainActivity>())
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel Module**

```
val viewModelModule = module {
    viewModel { PermissionViewModel(get()) }
}
```

then comes the PermissionRepositoryImplement

```
class PermissionRepositoryImplement(private val activity: Activity){
    companion object{
        private val map = Permission.values().associateBy(Permission::permissionValue)
        operator fun get(value: String) = (map[value] ?: error("NOT FOUND"))
    }

    enum class Key {
        granted, denied, forbidden
    }

    enum class Permission(val permissionValue: String) {
        WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), CAMERA(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), INTERNET(Manifest.permission.INTERNET), INTERNET_STATE(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE), NETWORK_STATE(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE),
    }

    private var result = HashMap<String, String>()

    fun requestPermission(permissionName: String): HashMap<String, String> {
        activity.let {
            it.askPermissions(get(permissionName).permissionValue) {
                onGranted {
                    result[permissionName] = Key.granted.name
                }
                onDenied {
                    result[permissionName] = Key.denied.name
                }
                onShowRationale { request ->
                    Snackbar.make(it.findViewById(R.id.container), String.format(it.getString(R.string.permissionRequested), Permission.values().filter { p -> p.permissionValue == permissionName }[0]), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction("Retry") { request.retry() }
                        .show()
                }
                onNeverAskAgain {
                    result[permissionName] = Key.forbidden.name
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

and finally the PermissionViewModel

```
class PermissionViewModel (private val permissionImplement: PermissionRepositoryImplement): ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableLiveData<CredentialsDataState>()
    val uiState: LiveData<CredentialsDataState> get() = _uiState

    fun requestPermission(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            runCatching {
                emitUiState(showProgress = true)
                permissionImplement.requestPermission(PermissionRepositoryImplement.Permission.CAMERA.permissionValue)
            }.onSuccess {
                emitUiState(result = Event(it))
            }.onFailure {
                emitUiState(error = Event(R.string.error))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun emitUiState(showProgress: Boolean = false, result: Event<HashMap<String, String>>? = null, error: Event<Int>? = null){
        val dataState = CredentialsDataState(showProgress, result, error)
        _uiState.value = dataState
    }

    data class CredentialsDataState(val showProgress: Boolean, val result: Event<HashMap<String, String>>?, val error: Event<Int>?)
}
```

until this section everything should work as koin need it.
But im always receiving the error that my PermissionRepositoryImplement isn't defined...

Answer (score 2):

```
val permissionsModule = module {
    scope<MainActivity> {
        scoped {
            PermissionRepositoryImplement(get<MainActivity>())
        }
    }
}
```

You have not provided the MainActivity instance to koin. That's why you are getting error.

As per my understanding we should not try to create android component{activity, broadcast receiver, service, content provider}
I will suggest extend PermissionRepositoryImplement with fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The current setup appears to be flawed. The ViewModel's lifecycle is longer than the Activity's, so injecting the Activity into the PermissionRepository and then into the ViewModel is not the intended way to use MVVM.
Instead, the PermissionRepository should not depend on the Activity. It can depend on the app context, which can be used to check the initial state of permissions with `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext, permission).`
A better structure would be to have the flow as:
PermissionRepository -> ViewModel -> Activity

Then, when a permission request is made in the Activity, it should notify the ViewModel, which can in turn notify the PermissionRepository.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `scope` before your `get()`/`inject()` method.

for example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), AndroidScopeComponent {
    override val scope: Scope by activityScope()

    val impl: PermissionRepositoryImplement = scope.get()
}
```